# Easy way to copy drush vget variables from one site to another site?

Tags: drush, configuration

I have a bunch of vget variables to copy over to another dev site. What is an easy way to do this? I'm able save it to a file via "drush vget | ack var_name > myfile", but how would i do a drush vset using those variables saved in the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the output from a `drush variable-get` might be an array.  Drush can easily render arrays on output, but `drush variable-set` does not provide a feature that allows you to provide arrays as input.

The best you can do with array data is to use php-eval:

`drush php-eval 'variable_set("var", array(...));'`

How do you get the `array` value to insert in here, though?  Trying to do this directly from the `drush variable-get` output would be problematic; it would be very tedious to get all of the quoting and escaping right. I would not recommend this for your final solution.

Instead, you might consider using drush_invoke_process.  Something similar to this might work:

`drush ev '$v = drush_invoke_process("@remote", "vget", array("var")); $data = $v["object"]; variable_set("var", $data);'`

That would probably do the trick for you. However, rather than building up a custom solution to moving configuration from one site to another with Drush, I might recommend that you instead examine the [ctools export bonus](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_ctex_bonus) Drush extension. It can export and import variables nicely, and might ultimately be better suited to your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could set them in [settings.php](https://www.drupal.org/node/1525472) or you could write some sort bash script to loop through your export file and set each one.